# Mac can't receive call transfer from iphone

Tags: iphone, mac, facetime

When I transfer a call from my MacBook Pro 2021 (Ventura 13.1) to my iPhone everything works perfectly. However, when I do the other way around, from my iPhone to my MacBook facetime opens (on the computer) and immediately shuts down the call.

I have tried the basic procedures, like switching on and off related options but this problem persists. I started experiencing this about a month ago and so far I could not find a solution to this problem.

Anyone around here has successfully dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, in Settings -> Cellular -> "Voice & Data" -> enable VoLTE.

I think enabling, VoWi-Fi (if that's an option), should also do it.