# iPhone calls keep dropping when switching on Mac

Tags: facetime, call

Answering phone calls on iPhone 13 (iOS 16) and then switching on Mac, causes call to drop.

What happens is that Mac's (Ventura 13.2) FaceTime opens the entire window, not just the small call window, and go fully dark.

Answering on Mac and then switching to iPhone works fine, but not the other way.

Comment: Same issue [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454209/119271) (no answers, yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iPhone, in Settings -> Cellular -> "Voice & Data" -> enable VoLTE.

I think enabling, VoWi-Fi (if that's an option), should also do it.